# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /temp.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android

I've been doing some experimenting, manipulating and exporting bitmaps, largely on a Galaxy Nexus (Jellybean). I kept running into this weird error, but couldn't find any answers that addressed my situation--now that I've figured it out, I wanted to share.

The "EROFS" error listed in the question title most commonly seems to occur when people hardcode a filename. I am properly using getExternalFilesDir(null), yet this problem continued to occur some of the time when I would call bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that when I had the directory open in a file management tool like ES File Explorer and then uninstalled and reinstalled the app (deleting the app-specific directory returned by getExternalFilesDir()), when it would try to create that directory there would be some sort of conflict, returning the mysterious "open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system" error, even though external storage is mounted for writing and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted.

So if you run into this error, make sure that you don't have the app's folder open in any other app when you uninstall and reinstall the app in development.